# Normal HTTP request vs TCP connection + HTTP header

Tags: qt, sockets, http, tcp, vlc

I'm trying to emulate http request using TCP connection + HTTP header.
I test it using VLC player. I use QT to develop my app.

So, basically I start streaming video in VLC player to host http://192.168.0.100:55555. Then in code I try to connect to the server via http GET request, which succeeds.

I would like instead of http request to connect by TCP to http://192.168.0.100:55555 and send plain GET request as a text using the same socket, but I get `QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError`.

```
QTcpSocket* socket = new QTcpSocket();
socket->connectToHost(m_session->remoteHost().address, m_session->remoteHost().port);
// Then I get QAbstractSocket::ConnectionRefusedError in a slot
// connected to error() signal
```

I wonder if it is possible to do so and if you have any suggestions.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Why not base your code from the [Http download example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-http-example.html)?

```
//...
    reply = qnam.get(QNetworkRequest(url));
//...
    connect(reply, SIGNAL(readyRead()),
        this, SLOT(httpReadyRead()));
//....
void HttpWindow::httpReadyRead()
{
    // this slot gets called every time the QNetworkReply has new data.
    // We read all of its new data and write it into the file.
    // That way we use less RAM than when reading it at the finished()
    // signal of the QNetworkReply
    if (file)
        file->write(reply->readAll());
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but that is not what I want. I know how to use qt network classes. I have a device with a special protocol and I need to send request and data in a special way. Qt doesn't seem to provide this functionality. I need to reuse the same port that is used by tcp connection for http, to send raw data to server. And this is not a post request that I need. The only thing that could work (but doesn't) is sendCustomRequest, but the QIODevice you put as a third parameter is never read. I have not seen a single working example of using sendCustomRequest.

Comment: Then, you might as well go all the way with a custom protocol on top of TCP and ditch HTTP. I'm saying this because re-implementing HTTP is not a good a idea as you will slowly have the need to re-implement little aspects you'll discover along you develop your application. Most probable, you'll implement them faulty and/or buggy (have you seen the [rfc](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html)?). One thing, though, is you can use [QHttpHeader](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhttpheader.html#toString) to get the std header as string.

Comment: I'm not going to reimplement HTTP. I have a concrete task, that will be finished as soon as I find how to reuse the same tcp connection for sending binary data to server, that was used by http GET request. That is it. Sounds easy, doesn't it? This is just how the device developers implemented it and I have no way to change it. So I expected an answer like 'There is no ways you can do that' or an explanation why I failed to do so and how to fix it. Thank you for `QHttpHeader` though, didn't know about it.